# Excluding null fields in super csv CsvBeanWriter

Tags: java, export-to-csv, supercsv

I have a class in which some of the fields may be null. I want to ignore such fields in my csv .Looking for functionality similar to @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL) in jackson. Null fields column header should also not come in CSV

Comment: you know if you export a list of these objects, your CSV will stop making sense, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you to (programatically) define the header, and which columns are written - Super CSV doesn't just automatically marshal an object to CSV for you (like Jackson does for JSON).

You should check out the documentation on the website - in particular the section on [partial writing](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_partial_writing.html).

Comment: I have programatically set the headers and based on my header it will pick the fields from my pojo . Which is perfect . Problem : I have a long field (epoch time) which i need to convert to human readable format i.e yyyy/mm/dd . This can be achieved by defining a processor. Processor should be in order of header define , which is little tough here since i am creating a set and adding headers in it programatically.